# why django form action url product/addcomment is redirect to product/addcomment twice?

Tags: python, css, django, sqlite

my English knowledge is so bad but i can understand.
when i click submit button get this error. i use python 3. and chrome browser. and also please help me ..
4 days i tried this problem. i think **http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/17/product/addcomment/17** this line twoise add **/product/17/** part. why it add please help me??
[submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuUTB.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7OMk.png)

product/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('addcomment/', views.addcomment, name='addcomment')
]
```

product/views.py

```
def addcomment(request):

    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')

    if request.method == 'POST':  # check post
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = Comment()  # create relation withmodel
            data.comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.product_id = id
            current_user = request.user
            data.user_id = current_user.id
            data.save()  # save data to table
            messages.success(request, 'Your Review Has be Send. Thank you for Your Review')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

home/urls.py

```
from home import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('home/', include('home.urls')),
        path('about/', views.aboutus, name='aboutus'),
        path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
        path('home/', include('home.urls')),
        path('product/', include('product.urls')),
        path('', include('home.urls')),
        path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
        path('category/<int:id>/<slug:slug>', views.category_products, name='category_products'),
        path('search/',views.search,name='search'),
        path('search_auto/',views.search_auto,name='search_auto'),
        path('product/<int:id>/<slug:slug>', views.product_details, name='product_details'),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

product/models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('True', 'True'),
        ('False', 'False'),
        ('New', 'New')
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='New')
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject


class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['subject', 'comment', 'rate']
```

html file

```
<form class="review-form" action="product/addcomment/{{ product.id }}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="subject" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Your Subject" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="comment" class="input" placeholder="Your review"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-rating">
        <strong class="text-uppercase">Your Rating: </strong>
        <div class="stars">
            <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" /><label for="star5"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" /><label for="star4"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" /><label for="star3"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" /><label for="star2"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" /><label for="star1"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% if user.id is not None %}
<button class="primary-btn">Submit</button>
      {% else%}
    First you need to Login
{% endif%}
</form>
```

Comment: submit button, error, links i added my error and submit button image.

Comment: Not Found: /product/17/product/addcomment/17     this is terminal get error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `/` at the start of action of the form tag. Try this,

```
<form class="review-form" action="/product/addcomment/{{ product.id }}" method="post">

...

</form>
```

And also there is no url endpoint in **product/urls.py** that matches `"/product/addcomment/{{ product.id }}"`. You can edit urls.py like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('addcomment/<int:product_id>', views.addcomment, name='addcomment')
]
```